# Discord.js API "Missing Access" while registering my slash commands

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I have a small discord bot I made 3 years ago in Typescript and is present on over 80 guilds, I recently decided to update it from `discord.js-v12.3.1-dev` to `discord.js-v13.6`, while adding the famous slash commands.

But when I register them with the discord.js's `Routes.applicationGuildCommands` routine in my "ready" event when I map over each Guild where my bot is present, the methode `Routes.applicationGuildCommands` return me an error `Missing Access` on most of my guilds (but not all !):

```
Trace: S[50001]: Missing Access
    at Q.runRequest (/home/user/bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/src/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.ts:487:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Q.queueRequest (/home/user/bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/src/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.ts:200:11)
    at async /home/user/bot/src/discord.ts:21:9
    at async Promise.all (index 50)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/home/user/bot/src/discord.ts:19:5) {
  rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
  code: 50001,
  status: 403,
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/642935463048642470/guilds/907457626412628088/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
}
    at /home/user/bot/src/discord.ts:21:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 50)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/home/user/botsrc/discord.ts:19:5)
```

Here is my code snipet (it's just some part of my code, I cut all unrelated part of the code).

> I know the methode `Routes.applicationCommands` exist but it's the same result, and I want to push my commands separatly over my guilds in order to traduct my commands descriptions later.

```js
import { Client, Intents, Guild } from 'discord.js';
import { REST                   } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { Routes                 } from 'discord-api-types/v9';
import * as commands              from "./commands/";

export const bot: Client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
  ]
});

bot.on("ready", async (): Promise<void> => {
    const commandsList: any[] = Object.keys(commands)?.map((name: string) => commands[name]);
    console.log(`Curently connected on (${bot.guilds.cache.size}) servers:`);
    await Promise.all(bot.guilds.cache.map(async (guild: Guild) => {
      try {
        await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(bot.user.id, guild.id), { body: commandsList });
        console.log(` - ${guild.name} ✔️`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(` - ${guild.name} ❌`);
        console.trace(error);
      }
    }));
    console.log(`${commandsList.length} imported command${commandsList.length ? 's' : ''}.`);
    await bot.user.setActivity("le Krosmoz", { type: "WATCHING" });
});
```

my `commandsList` object created at the first line of my `ready` event **is valid** and looks like this:

```js
commandsList = [
  {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Print the list of commands'
  },
  {
    name: 'toto',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
    options: [
      {
        name: 'date',
        description: "The toto's date",
        type: 3,
        required: false
      },
      {
        name: 'item',
        description: "The toto's item",
        type: 3,
        required: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code above somelike "works", but all my servers where my bots is present don't have the commands registered, a list of all my servers and if the `Routes.applicationGuildCommands` succeded or not is shown in the bot's console like this:

```
Curently connected on (9) servers:
 - Guild1 ❌
 - Guild2 ✔️
 - Guild3 ❌
 - Guild4 ❌
 - Guild5 ❌
 - Guild6 ❌
 - Guild7 ❌
 - Guild8 ✔️
 - Guild9 ❌
```

Resulting from the `console.log(` - ${guild.name} ✔️`);` or `console.log(` - ${guild.name} ❌`);`, (When the `❌` show up, it means the `Missing Access` where encountered).

**My question is**: How can I successfully register my slash commands on all my bot's guild ?

Some of it's guild where he successfully registered them (no `Missing Access` error and a `✔️`) don't have my bot's commands (even with reloading the discord clients and waiting for hours and days in case of cache's issues), some of my bot's guild where the `Missing Access` is encountered can still have the list of my bot's commands working...

When all my bot's guild added him, the `applications.commands` didn't even existed so may be if each guild's owner kick him and reinvite him would fix it, but a lot of bots (such as big one like MEE6, Tatsumaki & co) successfully pushed their slash commands regardless of their permissions on the guild, without needing to be kicked and reinvited. Even grant `administrator` permission on my bot's don't allow him to successfully register his commands on a mere test server.

I already read the whole "Application Commands" part of https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands 's guide but no clues, found on StackOverflow the `application.commands.update` scope should be added (but not present in my bot's portal).

**I am missing something ?**

> And I really don't wanna kick my bot of all of his guilds to reinvite it with the `applications.commands` scope while a lot of other bots didn't needed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your app does not have the applications.commands intent in a guild, it cannot create slash commands there. You could send a message in guilds with a new oauth link to add the bot with the applications.commands intent when someone uses a non-slash command.

Regarding:
And I really don't wanna kick my bot of all of his guilds to reinvite it with the applications.commands scope while a lot of other bots didn't needed to do it.

Discord added the applications.commands intent to all guilds with existing bots in them, but if the bot was added after this without the intent it wouldn’t work.

Comment: I don't believe you. I mean, like you said the `applications.commands` intent is enabled on most of the guilds (almost no one installed my bot since the `applications.commands` scope were created), and even on my personal guild, where the bot were added years ago, the permission "use slash commands" is given to the bot and users, even the "administrator" permission was granted and nothing change...
The bot and his slash commands works fine even on older server (I mean, where the bot was added before other guilds) so it's quite disruptive, it make no senses :/

Comment: @VolontéduPeuple If you change the bot’s role permissions, it doesn’t change the scope, and the only way to enable the scope is to reauthorize the application. https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#authorizing-your-application

Answer (score 0):

You need to to kick the bot from your server and make a new invite link with the scopes "bot" and "applications.commands" or else the bot will not be able  to modify the commands from the api.